# min and max value for date axis in amcharts4

Tags: charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a line graph with date axis and data being displayed in intervals for 30 or 15 minutes for a day. Since data is dynamic, for some cases data starts around 12 noon or some other time and hence the x-axis does not always starts from the 00:00. Similarly data might end before 12:00 Mid night.

I want to always show the dateAxis to start from 00:00 then some fix step for lets say a label for every one or two hours and end at 12:00 mid night. How can i do this?

I tried DateAxis.min and DateAxis.max. But these are only accepting numeric values. not sure how to set it to appropriate numeric value to represent the start and end of day.

I also tried setting DateAxis.extraMin and DateAxis.extraMax but these are working on percentage and its a but hard to find appropriate values for the dynamic data.

[This is how current graph renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3EKL.png)

[This is how i want to display (notice the empty labels at the start)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOJWU.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The min/max properties in DateAxis objects take millisecond timestamps. You can use the result of [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) from a JavaScript Date object:

```
dateAxis.min = (new Date(2019,7,10)).getTime();
dateAxis.max = (new Date(2019,7,10,23)).getTime();
```

There isn't a way to explicitly set a step, though. You can tweak `minGridDistance` to influence the step but that's about it. The only workaround you can use is insert guides ([Axis Ranges](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/#Ranges_as_guides)) at each timestamp with the appropriate label and disable the DateAxis' default labels.

```
    range.date = new Date(2019, 7, 10, 0);
    range.grid.strokeOpacity = .5;
    range.grid.stroke = "#cecece";
    range.label.text = "00:00";
```

Note that axis won't adjust label visibility in this case, so you may need to set a rotation on the range label as well.

Demo below:

```js
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = generateData();

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;

// Create value axis
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.name = "Sales";
series.strokeWidth = 3;
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;


dateAxis.baseInterval = {
  timeUnit: "minute",
  count: 15
}
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
dateAxis.min = (new Date(2019, 7, 10, 0)).getTime();
dateAxis.max = (new Date(2019, 7, 10, 23)).getTime();

generateRanges(dateAxis);

function generateRanges(axis) {
  var firstDate = new Date(2019, 7, 10, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
    var range = axis.axisRanges.create();
    var nextDate = new Date(firstDate);
    nextDate.setHours(i);
    range.date = nextDate;
    range.grid.strokeOpacity = .5;
    range.grid.stroke = "#cecece";
    range.label.text = ("0" + nextDate.getHours()).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + nextDate.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
    range.label.rotation = 90;
  }
}

function generateData() {
  var data = [];
  var firstDate = new Date(2019, 7, 10, 10);
  for (var i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    var nextDate = new Date(firstDate);
    nextDate.setMinutes(i * 15);
    data.push({
      date: nextDate,
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 15 + 5)
    })
  }
  return data;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 98vh;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: This does the job for me, thank you very much for your help @xorspark.